# Where should I use done()

Tags: node.js, postgresql, connection-pooling, pg

I am working under mobile backend using pg with connection pooling, now I meet the problem

**Error text**

`Error: connection pointer is NULL`

As I understand from this issue, https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/issues/182.

My question how `done()` works in pg, and where should I call it?

If I have for example multiple queries should be called one by one

```
pg.connect("constr", function(err,client,done) {
  if (err) callback(err);
  else {
    client.query("some query", function(err, result) {
       if (err) callback(err);
       else {
          client.query("one more", function(err, result) {
             if (err) callback(err);
             else {
                callback(null, result);
             }
          });
       }
    });
  }
});
```

Please explain me `done()` on this example.

Comment: what is `callback` in your code? I think you can safely do a search replace of callback with done ;)

Comment: @MukeshSoni it is refer to the top level, it callbacks to route/controller method which handles http request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will call done after you are done with the `client` -

```
 client.query("some query", function(err, result) {
       if (err) {
           done();
           callback(err);
       } else {
          client.query("one more", function(err, result) {
             done();
             if (err) callback(err);
             else {
                callback(null, result);
             }
          });
       }
    });
```

Comment: But what if my 'some query' has error , will my connection return to the pool?

Comment: done has nothing to do with error. It just releases the client back to the pool. Error might be because of various reasons like 'your db is down', 'invalid query' etc.

Comment: I know it, but in second line where if (err) ... else won't invoked, so done() will not invoked am I right?

Comment: that is right. So you should call done there too. I will edit the answer.

Comment: Thank you,I just wait for a while for more answer then accept it.

Comment: You never told me the solution for this problem - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21898837/session-store-destroy-event
I need to remember names.